# When should I return std::ostream?

Tags: c++, std, ostream

I return `std::ostream` every time I'm going to create an operator like `std::string` operator to show value (no operator), but I don't know why. If the `std::ofstream` is used as an function member operator function(`std::cout`), how can I return it, when should I do it and why?

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
   int val;
   std::ostream& operator<<(const std::ostream& os, const MyClass variable)
  {
      os << variable.val;
  }
}
```

On `std::string`:

```
std::string a("This is an example.");
std::cout << a;
```

Comment: Please, give at least concrete examples. It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: "string operator", use "ofstream as function"??? What the hell does that mean?

Comment: @texasbruce When I say `std::ofstream` as a function, I mean `std::cout << variable` (see edit).

Comment: If you mean use member operator function of ofstream object, that might be a better way to put it.

Comment: You usually return a parameter if you pass it by reference, and you want to `chain-it-up` the function calls.

Comment: @texasbruce It still unclear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's conventional to return a reference to the `ostream` when overloading `<<`, to allow chaining. This:

```
s << a << b;
```

is equivalent to the function calls

```
operator<<(operator<<(s,a),b);
```

and only works because the inner call returns a suitable type to be an argument to the outer call.

To implement this, simply take the stream argument by reference, and return the same stream by reference, either directly:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, thing const & t) {
    // stream something from `t` into `s`
    return s;
}
```

or as returned from some other overload:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, thing const & t) {
    return s << t.whatever();
}
```